# How to use WebAii and WatiN with Same Browser

Tags: c#, watin, webaii

I wrote too much tests in watin and all they work. there is a silverlight upload control in a page and I must use webaii to control that. but I don't want to convert all my watin code to webaii. How can I use watin and webaii with one browser tab?

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with webaii, but if I were you I'd try this:  Use webaii to launch the browser then use the WatiN browser .AttachTo() method to get WatiN to point at the browser that webaii opened.